# Swift-app crashes on row selection in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm having problems with a UITableView in Swift.
It works fine as long as I don't implement the delegate function for handling cell selection.

Here's my very simple class that acts as the table view delegate and data source:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewService : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "One"
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Two"
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    return cell;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    log.debug("Row selceted")
}
}
```

As soon as I select a row in the table view, the app crashes with a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error in objc_msgSend - there's no error logged in the console, and if I put a breakpoint in on the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function, it never gets triggered.

[image: Crash screenshot]

Any ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: wanna show the view controller's code where your tableview is implemented?

Comment: What is `log` and have you initialized it for that class?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel - the log instance is a global XCLogger. It's not relevant in this case though. It doesn't matter what code I put in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function - it still crashes.

Comment: @AndreSlotta - my ViewController basically only loads a NIB file that contains the table view. I have setup the delegate and datasource as Objects in the NIB file. Maybe it's better to set them manually from the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to create your project with no issue.  Maybe it will help incase you missed a step somewhere?:

1) Set up `UITableView` in storyboard as a subview of `ViewController`

2) Add code to `ViewController` (your custom class)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!
    let tableService:TableViewService = TableViewService()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         tableView.delegate = tableService
         tableView.dataSource = tableService
    }
}
```

3) ensure the outlet is connected between `ViewController` and `tableView`

4) `TableViewService` class is copy/pasted from your code above (with the exception that I am using `println()` instead of `log.debug`)

If I make sure of these 3 things, then I am able to see that the delegate method is called with no crash.

Comment: I have setup the delegate and datasource as Objects in a NIB file. Maybe it's better to set them manually from the view controller - I will try that approach instead.

Comment: It works when setting the data source and delegate in code. I guess that suits me right for being lazy and doing it in Interface Builder instead. :)

Comment: Glad my approach above should work fine for you :)  Though I'm curious what you mean that you set them up as "Objects" - plural.  You should be able to add a single Object to your NIB, ensure that it is of the correct class `TableViewService`, connect the `tableView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` directly to this object.  Make sure they are disconnected to the `ViewController`  This approach also worked for me.

Comment: Sorry - my full app has two table views with separate service objects as data source / delegates. So I have one Object for each, hence the plural. As long as this approach works - I'll just leave it as is.